# Split a Set-Cookie header with multiple cookies

Tags: javascript, regex, cookies

I'm working with Serverless framework (Javascript) and it requires me to split a single `Set-Cookie` into an array of cookies for it to be correctly set on the client. Why? No idea, but this seems to be what is going on.

I do not have access to the code that generates the `Set-Cookies` string, so I have to manually split it into an array.

My string looks like this:

```
cookie1=value, cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu, 06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT;
```

You can probably guess my issue, if I do `string.split(', ')` my string is split in three:

1. `cookie1=value`
2. `cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu`
3. `06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT;`

I've Googled but I cannot find an already existing answer anywhere. I know I can probably resolve this with Regex, but it's far too complex for me to figure it out.

Comment: Does it allow for localStorage instead of cookies?

Comment: It's on a server, and it has to be returned into a Set-Cookies array so that it can be set on the client. So, no unfortunately...

Comment: So this is a spicy subject, because any HTTP header that appears multiple times can be combined in a single comma-separated header.

EXCEPT, `Set-Cookie` is the _only_ exception to this and specifically called out: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#section-5.3 Whatever framework or library you're using should never have combined these to a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some suggestions I happened to discover the [`getSetCookie()` method on mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/getSetCookie).

For some reason this isn't typed on the `Headers` class but it does work.

So if your response returns a header Object you can pass it to the header class and then use the built-in method.

```js
const headers = new Headers(res.headers);
const setCookies = headers.getSetCookie()
console.log(setCookies)
// ["cookie1=value", "cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu, 06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT;"
```

Depending on what you're doing your response might already return headers as an instance of `Headers`, so keep an eye on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let aList = [];
let s = 'cookie1=value, cookie2=value2; Expires=Thu, 06 Jul 2023 14:45:25 GMT;'
for (const match of s.matchAll(/cookie\d+=([^;,]+)(?:,|;)/g)) {
      console.log(`matched: ${match[1]}`);
      aList.push(match[1])
} 
console.log(aList)
//(2) ['value', 'value2']
```

First part matches cookie word followed by a digit and an equal sign.
Capture group matching one or more characters that are that are not semicolon or comma. It captures the value of cookie.